# IDialogContentStyleProps isMultiLine property

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

What exactly is affected when isMultiLine set to True for the Dialog widget?  I've tried setting that and don't see any visual difference.

Comment: I don't know is this a writing mistake but the property is `isMultiline` not `isMultiLine`. Inside documentation it says thats a multiline wrapper inside content area.

Comment: Yes, just a case-sensitive typo.  I read the doc but what does that actually mean?  What behavior changes when set to true vs false?

Comment: I found this https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/master/packages/react/src/components/Dialog/DialogContent.styles.ts#L123 that might help.... That condition only affects font-size but visually its still the same :)